# Angular Twix Editor does not send value with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, text-editor, angularjs-ng-model

I have a problem. I want to add text editor on my page. I choose **Angular-twix** editor. I added on my page and connected with controller. I initialize first value for text editor. There is no problem to get value but when I write some text, **ng-model** does not send

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.writing.newcontent')
      .controller('newcontentCtrl',['$scope','$sce','$http', '$translate','$filter', 'toastr', 'serverNode','newContentServices','categoryServices','tagServices', newcontentCtrl]);
      
     function newcontentCtrl($scope, $sce, $http, $translate, $filter, toastr, serverNode, newContentServices, categoryServices, tagServices) { 
       $scope.newWriting ={
                title:"First Title",
                text:"First Text",
                customField:"",
                category:"",
                tags:"",
                status:"",
                publistTime:"",
                publishDate:""
            };
       
       console.log($scope.newWriting.text);
       
           }
}) ();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<trix-editor class="trix-content" style="color: white; min-height: 200px;" placeholder="Enter Text" angular-trix ng-model="newWriting.text">
            </trix-editor>
```

value to controller.

Comment: have you got solving for the problem, i'm also facing with same issue.
would you please help me out how you have resolve this issue.